# how to disable $ character escaping on command line

Tags: shell, quoting

I read countless threads about this but none address this issue.

I need to have a MySQL expression executed on the command line
that expression contains `$` that are escaped and so ruins MySQL behavior

```
mysql -u root -p -e "some statement that change a pa$$word"
```

someone told me to check it with `printf`

```
printf "%q\n" 'pa$$word'
pa\$\$word
```

so I need to not escape the `$` otherwise the wrong password is fed into MySQL query.

Comment: Using single quote instead of double quote

Answer (score 9):

You misunderstand some mechanisms.

When you put a phrase in single quotes, ie `'`, there's no expansion and you don't have to escape the `$`s. Expansion means there are special characters like `$`, which if unescaped, trigger special shell procedures. So when you suppress expansion with single quotes, you don't need to escape them. Thus use:

```
mysql -u root -p -e 'some statement that change a pa$$word'
```

As for `printf`, what you did is not checking. Calling it with `%q` adds the backslashes to the `$`s.

If something didn't work, it was because `$$` got changed into the PID (process id) of the shell. That's what the shell makes of this combination of special characters in its normal context, ie. when they are not escaped or put within single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me,

```
$ mysql -uroot -p'secret' -e "UPDATE users SET
password='pa\$\$word',email='foobar@example.com' WHERE id = 1;"
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Now the mysql string has single quotes for `pa$$word`. Is that what you had in mind? If correct: The process to get here should be informative any way.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas escaping `$` wouldn't work ?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, escaping is another way of quoting. `-e "UPDATE users SET
password='pa\$\$word' … "`

Comment: @BinaryZebra thanks, I was not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want `$variable` expansion, I see three options:

1. Use single quotes instead of double quotes (but then you will need to escape the single quotes in your statement! So you still need to *properly* handle escaping!
2. Use a different shell, one that does not support `$variables` (I'm not aware of any good shell that doesn't)
3. Actually *use* variables instead to your benefit (but beware, you still need to handle SQL escaping to avoid sql injection attacks):

I.e. you can do this (beware, the exact notion for setting the variable varies with your shell! Below is untested, just to give the idea):

```
 pass='pa$$word'
 mysql -whatever "dangerous sql injection statement '$pass' if you cannot trust the pass variable"
```

But **use prepared statements** and a programming language designed for this, rather than a shell script. It's much less likely to break.

Remember [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). What if someone chose the password `');DROP TABLE users; --`? That's a pretty secure password, isn't it? **Sanitize your inputs - and doing so in shell is a pain, so don't use shell for this task**.
For more details, please refer to this book:
[image: O'rly drop table animals]

Comment:  See also [How to prevent SQL injection in MySQL's command-line shell interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4450747)